# spinner and button in android with clickhandler

Tags: android, button, spinner

i try make spinner and button with clickHandler

this is my nyoba.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class nyoba extends Activity {
    String[] nama_hari = {"Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu","Kamis","Jum'at","Sabtu","Minggu"};
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     Spinner  spinner1;
     Button btnSubmit;
     TextView textView1;
     String tes;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nama_hari);
           aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner1.setAdapter(aa);
    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,  
            int arg2, long arg3) {  
            tes =  nama_hari[arg2]; 
    }  
    public void clickHandler(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnSubmit:
         textView1.setText(tes); 
            break;
}
    }
}
```

and this is my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">



        <LinearLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip"
          >

          <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />


        </LinearLayout>


  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

but when i run it to emulator,and i choose 1 option in spinner and click the button , the TextView doesn't show up the word from spinner which i choose

(for example, i choose "senin" at spinner, and click the button, but the text "senin" doesn't appear in the TextView )

i check DDMS and there are no error.....

is the code wrong?
can you help me please which one is wrong?

Thank anyway....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't set the selection listener on your spinner.

But actually you can just retrieve the spinner's selected position with `getSelectedItemPosition` in the click handler of your button:

Try this:

```
public void clickHandler(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnSubmit:
        textView1.setText(nama_hari[spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, `onItemSelected` is not bound to the Spinner, which is why `tes` is empty.